# LWC Object converted to Proxy

Tags: lightning-web-components, error, proxy

I am calling my Apex controller from connectedCallback and assigning a variable the value od data wich is returned by method.
I am able to view the data when it is returned correctly in component but as soon as I assign it to a variable and I retreive it it is converted to Proxy objects. If I pass the data to child component In remains as the Proxy.

Comment: This is normal behavior. If you have a specific problem you're trying to solve, please [edit] your question to explain why this is causing a problem.